# Removing any non-letter from an NSString

Tags: objective-c

I am trying to remove from an `NSString` link , some characters that are not letters, that may appear at the start and and the end. Is there a simple, but safe way to do that ?

example :

```
NSString *link= @" www.something.com. "  //removing the `.`
NSString *link= @" [www.something.com] "  //removing the `[ ]`
NSString *link= @" www.something.com/ "  //removing the `/`
```

Thanks a lot.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To remove unwanted characters from the start and end of the given string,
use `stringByTrimmingCharactersInSet`:

```
NSString *link= @" www.something.com. ";
NSCharacterSet *charset = [[NSCharacterSet letterCharacterSet] invertedSet];
NSString *stripped = [link stringByTrimmingCharactersInSet:charset];
```

Answer (score 1):

Just use this:

```
    NSCharacterSet *notAllowed = [[NSCharacterSet characterSetWithCharactersInString:@"abcdefghijklmnopqrstuvwxyzABCDEFGHIJKLMNOPQRSTUVWXYZ"] invertedSet];
    NSString *resultString = [[yourString componentsSeparatedByCharactersInSet:notAllowed] componentsJoinedByString:@""];
```

Comment: Thanks, but is this removes only the first and the last at the string?

Comment: this is not a good answer. you remove all the non letters from the whole string ....